# Content Provider Android

Tags: android, locale, android-contentprovider

```
    // Defines an object to contain the updated values
ContentValues mUpdateValues = new ContentValues();

// Defines selection criteria for the rows you want to update
String mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE +  "LIKE ?";
String[] mSelectionArgs = {"en_%"};

// Defines a variable to contain the number of updated rows
int mRowsUpdated = 0;

...

/*
 * Sets the updated value and updates the selected words.
 */
mUpdateValues.putNull(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE);

mRowsUpdated = getContentResolver().update(
    UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,   // the user dictionary content URI
    mUpdateValues                       // the columns to update
    mSelectionClause                    // the column to select on
    mSelectionArgs                      // the value to compare to
);
```

What is This  UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE +  "LIKE ?";

What Is The Purpose OF + "LIKE ?"; Here.. What Is Content_URI

What The Whole Code Is Actually Doing..

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/

> Content providers manage access to a structured set of data. They
>   encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for defining data
>   security. Content providers are the standard interface that connects
>   data in one process with code running in another process.

The code is querying one of the built-in Content Providers in the Android platform. In this case, it is updating all rows in the user dictionary table identified by `UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI` that match the selection clause, that is, all rows whose the local column (`UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE`) are `LIKE "en_%"`. The question mark is a placeholder that will be replaced by the `"en_%"` value. All rows whose locale has the language "en" will be updated to null (`mUpdateValues.putNull(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE);`)

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Comment: Thanks Motamira..
If We Dont Add  "LIKE ?";
Below
String mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE +  "LIKE ?";


LIke This
String mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE;
What Can Be The Problem..?

Comment: The selection `mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE;` is not valid. Thus no rows should be updated. The selection should be a mix of logical and Boolean expressions, column names, and values. E.g., `UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE = ?`. If you do not specify a selection clause all the rows would be updated to null.